# android XML view Does not display ToggleButton in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, layout

In my android XML Graphical Layout, I am unable to display my `ToggleButton`. I receive some errors (see below). Also, I am not able to edit anything else using the Graphical Layout.

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.thunder4apps.lanterna.corinthians.MainActivity" >



    <ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="Vibrate on"
    android:textOff="Vibrate off"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Error :

```
Exception raised during rendering: -1
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogThe graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session)
Path.isConvex is not supported. (Ignore for this session)
```

Comment: Is that the complete xml? I assume you have xml element that uses a shape...

Answer (score 5):

Go to your graphical layout and locate the drop down of the API levels, probably you are using the last one 21, and you don´t have it installed, change to other lever according to your app.

[image]

Comment: I have api level 21 and its installed but still its showing this error but when i changed it into level 8 its not showing the error then , why , is it anything different in level 21 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think You haven't got the right android packages installed. Make sure your API is set to the correct one (As in not android wear). Just click on you SDK manager and install the correct api. including all the extras. cheers !