# Unable to create a ToggleButton in Eclipse IDE for android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-togglebutton

In my android XML Graphical Layout, it can not display my `ToggleButton`. I get some errors (see below). I have checked all other components in the Palette window and the only component that fails to load is `ToggleButton`. The problem is not project specific. It persists in every project I create.

**Note:** I have tried dragging it directly as well as using XML code to generate it. But it fails either way and the error is same.

Error :

```
Exception raised during rendering: -1
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session)
Path.isConvex is not supported. (Ignore for this session)
```

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577315/android-xml-view-does-not-display-togglebutton-in-eclipse) question and tried to edit it but the edit was rejected. So please do not redirect me there.

I am using API 21. All the build tools are installed.

Comment: try to switch in [`android studio`](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) as it is official IDE

Comment: I used a `checkbox` instead of `togglebutton` but I would really like to know why the `togglebutton` is not working.

Comment: I can add that the same problem arises in Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved by changing my target device screen to any of the xhdpi OR xxhdpi devices.
I'm sorry but I'm not able to post images yet, all you have to do is go to the dropdown menu just above the graphical layout -> General OR Google -> Select the xhdpi/xxhdpi target device you prefer.
I'm also new to android so I'm not able to explain why this is happening, I can only guess it's a compatibility issue or something. I'll try finding out more..
 
In the meantime I hope this will turn useful for you as well :-)

Comment: Did you find out why?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your background drawable. Corners of your rectangle can be rounded all only by a same amount. Just like your error message says. You must set them all to same amount.

Comment: How shall I do it ? I am using the default `ToggleButton` without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the display theme so ensure that the theme you select matches the `android:theme` in your `activity` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.  In Android Studio (sorry not eclipse as per question) in the top bar of the preview panel, I had to click the current theme name (which was `Light`) which brings up the `Select Theme` panel and then choose my theme under `Project Themes` (as I had a custom theme - you location may vary).

Comment: Thanks. For me setting API in Android Studio to 19 solved the preview problem.