# I need to make Toggle Button in Android layout

Tags: android

When I make a toggle button, this message appears in layout

> "Exception raised during rendering: -1
>   Exception details are logged in
>   Windows > Show View > Error LogThe graphics preview in the layout
>   editor may not be accurate:
>   Different corner sizes are not supported
>   in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session) Path.isConvex is not
>   supported. (Ignore for this session)"

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etCommands"
    android:password="true"
    android:hint="Type a Command"
 />

<LinearLayout 
    android:weightSum="100" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:id="@+id/bResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ToggleButton 
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="ToggleButton" android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

   </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvReslts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="invalid" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post some code

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="25dp">

Comment: this is the start of the code  .... and the rest up

Comment: Hi @predactor i think here is a prefect solution for you  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961982/unable-to-create-a-togglebutton-in-eclipse-ide-for-android?lq=1