# Android Studio: Toggle Button gives me error stating Path.isConvex is not supported. (Ignore for this session)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, togglebutton

I'm using a ToggleButton for an activity, but I'm receiving the following error in the rendering window:

> - Path.isConvex is not supported. (Ignore for this session)

I'm currently on Api 23 for testing, and switching to api 17 solves the problem however, I'm wondering if this will causes errors in mobile phones with newer firmware (api levels).

Is there a way to fix this on newer api levels so that the rendering window will stop showing this error?

Here's my current xml file where the error is appearing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/top_bar_2">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">


    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/BoldButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="B"
        android:textOn="B"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/ItalicsButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="I"
        android:textOn="I"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/UnderlineButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="U"
        android:textOn="U" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tr_underline"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_toolbox"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tr_linkifications"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_toolbox"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tr_size"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_toolbox"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/tr_search"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_toolbox"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: see answers on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577315/android-xml-view-does-not-display-togglebutton-in-eclipse) and [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-the-error-path-isconvex-is-not-supported-in-Android-Studio)

Comment: I'm able to view the toggle buttons on my device when running the app, but the error is there in the rendering window of android studio, which has me concerned. I'm also not using any rounded corners.

Comment: Invalidate cahce and restart studio works for me

Comment: Invalidating the cache didn't seem to work for me

Comment: It seems to run fine on my android device but the error is still there on the rendering window for higher api levels